# overflow out of overflow:hidden container without changing HTML structure

Tags: html, css

I have a parent element with overflow:hidden and two overlapping children. I want one child to listen to overflow:hidden and one defies it. Right now, both children listen to overflow:hidden. I want to defy overflow hidden!

```
<div class="ihave-overflow-hidden">
  <div class="i-will-not-overflow">Some text</div>
  <div class="but-i-will-overflow">I'm a Popover and popovers should always overflow</div>
</div>
```

I want class "but-i-will-overflow" to overflow out of parent-class "ihave-overflow-hidden".

note: this html setup cann
Unfortunately, I cannot change the html structure here so i must use pure css with these class (:after & :before are not allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/42/

**CSS**

```
.ihave-overflow-hidden {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.i-will-not-overflow {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.but-i-will-overflow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will get a result that you're looking for:

```
.ihave-overflow-hidden{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 15px;
    width: 30px;
}
.i-will-not-overflow{
    position: inline;
}
.but-i-will-overflow{
    position: absolute;
}
```

By making the second one as overflow it ignores the parents overflow.

Comment: The problem with this is that only works if .ihave-overflow-hidden has position: static. That could make the absolutely positioned child hard to position - depending on the markup and the positioning of parents.